# Showing polar coordinate map is a smooth map

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, analysis, smooth-manifolds

Rigorously, how can I show that the polar coordinates map is smooth? I've never seen this done before so I am curious how to do it. Usually they just neglect it and just say it's smooth.

$$
f_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \quad(r, \varphi) \mapsto(x, y):=(r \cos \varphi, r \sin \varphi)
$$

Is there some way I should look at the coordinate maps to determine if it is smooth or not?

Comment: Here, it is important that you say what's the definition of "smooth map". Because, the mapping $f(x,y)=(f_{1},f_{2})$, where $f_{1}: (x,y)\mapsto r\cos \varphi$ and $f_{2}: (x,y)\mapsto r\sin \varphi$ are functions in $C^{\infty}$, then $f\in C^{\infty}$, does it mean $f$ is smooth map?

Comment: How much multivariable calculus do you know? Products of smooth maps are smooth, which is a pretty basic fact. And I assume you know $(r,\phi)\mapsto r$ and $(r,\phi)\mapsto \cos\phi$ and $(r,\phi)\mapsto \sin\phi$ are smooth (pretty much) from single-variable calculus; the first is a polynomial, and the other two are basic trigonometric functions.

Comment: So I could say $(r,\phi) \mapsto r \cos \phi$ and $(r,\phi) \mapsto r \sin \phi$ are smooth since products of smooth maps are smooth. How could I say that $(r,\phi) \mapsto ( r\sin \phi, r \cos \phi)$ is smooth?

Comment: A map $f:U\subset \Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ is ($*$) if and only if for each $i\in\{1,\dots, m\}$, $f_i$ is ($*$). Here, ($*$) can be any of the following: *“continuous at a point $p\in U$”*, *“differentiable at a point $p\in U$”*, *“continuous on $U$”*, *“differentiable on $U$”*, *”$C^k$ on $U$”*, *”smooth on $U$”*, *”analytic on $U$”*. These are basic properties which you should prove directly from the relevant definitions. One helpful tool is the use of the linear projections $\pi_i:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}$ and injections $\iota_i:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^m$ (and the relevant facts about compositions).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Do you happen to have a source where this is proven? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I won’t comment further. I’ll let you spend some time to think about it. These are basic facts and you should really prove them one by one (ignore my comment about projections and injections; that merely offers a somewhat slicker proof). You should “struggle” with such basic questions till they become ‘obvious’. It’s pretty straightforward to come up with proofs straight from the definitions via $\epsilon$-$\delta$ for continuity/differentiability; the smoothness claims follow immediately. These are usually left as exercises in texts such as Spivak/Munkres.